Do a person has to make up his invalid salahs after leaving islam and then again joining it?
Assalamu alaikum.
I know these are very, very bad things I did but some of the things I was genuinely ignorant about since I was in 10 grade when I joined Islam and I came to know about it from internet. I don't have any Muslim person in real life to tell me about these things.
I am a revert but later left the Islam. I realized my mistake and did my shahada again. I'm a Muslim again. But I have a question: when I first became a Muslim I did many prayers wrong like horrible pronunciation that are straight up many times wrong, didn't did salam at the end of prayer which is is a pillar of prayer (I knew about that it was essentialwhen I did not do Salam at one prayer because of fear lf parents and society). Didn't knew about wudu or forget about it before doing Prayer etc things like that.
Since I  left islam and joined again, do I have to repeat or make up all these players again?

Wa Alaikkum wa salaam
Welcome back to Islam. You are lucky to be blessed again with Islam. I hope you always pray to remain steadfast in Islam.
Regarding prayers that you left when left Islam, I didn't see any evidence of prophet(s.a) asking anyone to perform prayer for their non muslim period. So just make sure you always try to remain steadfast in prayer in future.
